# YouTube API appears no longer available

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The following URL no longer appears to return, EG:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/59787513DAFB0226

Just returns 'No longer available'

I do know Playlist is fine and correct.

Could anyone help? Is this API deprecated?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: This is an endpoint for the version 2 API.  You should now be using the v3 API.  Please see the many posts on StackOverflow on how to migrate to the new endpoints.

Comment: @JAL Many thanks for the confirmation, I did do some searching around, but obviously not well enough. Regards

Answer (score 7):

[API v2 is turned down](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html). You can use [Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation) to migrate your app.

Comment: is there a way in the V3 to filter the videos based on a publish date. for now i m doing the filtering on the client side. in the V2 i used to have entry[xs:dateTime(published)>xs:dateTime('2015-06-26T00:56:33.7414268Z')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link with your Youtube channel id after the = and it should work.

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=your youtube channel id number